# Horizontal scroll plus Vertical scroll in Android on one Activity

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview, vertical-scrolling

I want to implement a 2d Scroll in one of my activity in Android.

I am able to create either a vertical or horizontal scroll view and i am able to do all my on that but my problem is i want to implement both scrollview in a single activity. is this really possible?
I have searched in internet for an hour and dint get any convincing answer on this. Please help

Comment: what content your activity is having?

Comment: vertical scrollview has 30+ lines of text and then after a horizontal scroll new lines will appear

Comment: From the content you plan on having, although that may be achieved, I would advice against it, I don't think the navigation seems user friendly.

Comment: any other suggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **ListView** in **HorizontalScrollView**.

**ListView** will have virticle Scroll

where as

**HorizontalScrollView** will have horizontal scroll

you can put your String lines in listView with listAdapter

Comment: vertical scroll view content is a long string not a list of options.

Comment: If you have string lines and want both the scrolls then this is the best way.

Comment: You have to make list item and in list item you can use multi-line textView to hold your long text